# View Binding and Text Watcher

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, include, android-viewbinding, android-textwatcher

Is there anything I am missing while using View Binding in on Text Changed Listener. It is not working but outside the text watcher it works fine. Actually my code starts as binding.include.tv1.setText() but not working inside on TextChangedListener. Can anyone help please.

I am trying to use view binding with include layout inside a fragment and a text watcher. It is absolutely working but outside text watcher and not within it.please advise.